# Unable to start Celery in Flask application

Tags: python-3.x, flask, celery

I am getting the following error when trying to start a Celery worker (Windows).

I'm using Celery 5.0.5.

`celery.exe -A api.app` -> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'`

**main.py**

```
import os

from api.app import create_app

app = create_app(os.getenv("FLASK_ENV"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

**api\app.py**

```
from celery import Celery
from flask import Flask
from flask_redis import FlaskRedis
from flask_restful import Api
from api.config import env_config


redis_client = FlaskRedis()
celery = Celery(__name__, broker="redis://...")


def create_app(config_name):
    import resources

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(env_config[config_name])
    redis_client.init_app(app)

    app.config.update(
        CELERY_BROKER_URL="redis://...",
        CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND="redis://..."
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    with app.app_context():
        from .routes import ccl_routes
        from .routes import scan_routes

    return app
```

Folder structure is like so:

```
helheim
| |api
|   |app.py
|   |__init.py__
|main.py
```

What am I doing wrong? It's late here so probably something obvious but can't see it :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

edit: i think u can try `celery -A api.app.celery worker` before doing any major changes.

not sure how your entire file structure looks like but for example

```
project
| |_api
|   |_app
_...
```

you should start it with `celery -A project.api.app.celery worker`. replace `.celery` to your celery instance name. or you can also refer to this repo https://github.com/mushcatshiro/flask-template.

also note, its a bit challenging to work with celery 4.X on windows from my experience, use celery 5.0 instead.

Comment: That didn't quite work for me. I've updated my question with my folder structure

Comment: hmmm in my case i have a separate file to call the celery instance `flask-template/backend/celery_worker.py` which u might want to try it out. i know its kinda messy to have one additional file but that the only way so far that managed to get things working.

Comment: create a `__init__.py` file under `helheim`, and start celery in a separate terminal with `celery -A helheim.api.app.celery worker`